# 素晴らしいと思える回答にお礼をつける方法はありますでしょうか

Tags: サポート

質問をして、回答を頂いたなかで、内容が非常に具体的かつ明確で、おそらくOSなどのソースコードを読まなければならないような労力も使ったであろう回答に対して、お礼を出したいと思うことがあります。

例：
[.bashrcでexportしたPATHが/procにあるプロセスファイルの環境変数(PATH)と一致しないように見える](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/19984/bashrc%E3%81%A7export%E3%81%97%E3%81%9Fpath%E3%81%8C-proc%E3%81%AB%E3%81%82%E3%82%8B%E3%83%97%E3%83%AD%E3%82%BB%E3%82%B9%E3%83%95%E3%82%A1%E3%82%A4%E3%83%AB%E3%81%AE%E7%92%B0%E5%A2%83%E5%A4%89%E6%95%B0path%E3%81%A8%E4%B8%80%E8%87%B4%E3%81%97%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84%E3%82%88%E3%81%86%E3%81%AB%E8%A6%8B%E3%81%88%E3%82%8B)

ただ、そのやり方がわからないのと、あったとしてそれを使っても良いと思われる基準と、そもそもそういう機能があるのかいまいちわかりませんでした。

自分のことで恐縮ですが、自分の出した回答に対して、回答後に突然お礼といいましょうか、多分それだと思うんですが、３００ポイントが追加されたことがあったので何かしらあるのだと考えています。

初歩的な質問と思いますが、このことについて教えていただけるとありがたいです。

Answer (score 5, accepted):

「回答の承認」や「プラス投票」だけでなく、さらにお礼をしたい場合には、文字通り「お礼（bounty）」という機能で信用度を贈与することができます。

- [お礼とは?どうしたら開始できますか? - ヘルプ センター](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/bounty)
- [How does the bounty system work? - Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/16067/286934)

十分な回答が得られていない質問をアピールするのに使われる機能ですが、既存の回答にお礼をする時にもお使いいただけます。

ただ、あなたが挙げられた質問は投稿から 48 時間経っていないため、それを過ぎてからになります。